# Chromium logging me out when I'm switching between desktops

Tags: linux, chrome

When I'm switching between GNOME and KDE, every time I'm being logged out from Chromium (from Google account) as well from all other websites. However, my browser history, extensions bookmarks and so on are still in place. Is there a way to fix that or make some work around?

I'm using latest version of Manjaro Linux and Chromium.
I've also noticed, that browser is using two different keyrings, one on each desktop.